# New declined flag nag goes poorly with the uncertainty of declined flags

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Until tonight, I've never paid any attention to the disposition of my flags. My flag limit is high, it's never decreased, so, pretty clearly, on average I'm not doing anything too silly.

However, for the first time, this evening I was presented with a message:

"Your last flag was declined by a moderator. Please review it before flagging this post."

OK, I clicked on the link. Which took me to a deleted answer. A deleted answer which I had, indeed, flagged as 'not an answer.'

I assume that this is one of those cases where the diamond winds up declining a flag due to some matter of flag mechanics. Fine, I don't care; but it seems unhelpful to, on the one hand, not give mods the ability to avoid unwanted flag declines and on the other hand nag flaggers about declined flags.

At least this message is more polite than a review queue failure.

Comment: This warning only appears if you've had less than 10 flags in the past week -- it seems that it's meant for infrequent/inexperienced flaggers.

Comment: I found that wording to be very confusing - wasted a few minutes looking for some "review the flag" button, based on how we generally use that "review" word around the site. Was even more confused when I realised the warning was just telling me to look at my flag having been rejected, so that I could disagree with the reason for the rejection.

Comment: +1.  Comments on my situation at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254628/flag-declined-a-moderator-reviewed-your-flag-but-found-no-evidence-to-support#comment25840_254628  . In my case, I think the issue was that the requested migration turned out to be unnecessary because the questions had already been cross-posted or were cross-posted by the OP in response to my comments.  So my tentative conclusion is that the moderators did **not** actually disagree with my flags.  Is there a possibility of a "decline flag without prejudice" option for moderators in this case?

Comment: Same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937208 -- I flagged as "Please migrate to ServerFault", and the question was subsequently deleted by the OP.  The question _clearly_ merits migration, so the flag warning is just confusing.